# ChangeNotifier can't no longer be used in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am a beginner in Flutter, and I am trying to use Riverpod. here is the sample code

import "package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart";

```
class CounterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _value = 0;
  int get value => _value;

  void incrementValue() {
    _value++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

but I have error, I can't find `ChangeNotifier` and `notifyListeners()` like this

[image]

in pubspec.yaml file, I am using `flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3`

am I misising something?

Comment: In my case i tried to check my ChangeNotifier class it say from ```package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart```

Comment: @Reign yup, thats the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChangeNotifier is a Flutter class, not a Riverpod one; when working with it, you have to ensure you have imported it.

It gets bundled in with common imports such as `package:flutter/material.dart`, and as [Reign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12789200/reign) mentioned in his comment, can be directly imported via `package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart`.